# Repeating C# Regex replace

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to create a small tool to convert some code.

Most of it can be done by Regex, so I do not need an actual parser.

But there is a problem with repeating patterns.
Below a simplified sample:

```
var nl = Environment.NewLine;
var temp = 
@"Other things
End
End
Other things";

temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"(\r\nEnd\r\n)+",@"" + nl + "}" + nl + "");
```

This will return

```
Other things
}
End
Other things
```

So the second End is not replaced. (except if I execute the same Regex.Replace twice)

Any idea how to solve this?

Best regards

Comment: At https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex show how to use the regular expression.  It is very fast to read and quite interesting !!

Comment: also, for quick testing:https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because matches can't overlap. You have

```
Other things\r\n
End\r\n
End\r\n
Other things\r\n
```

that is matched as

```
Other things***From Here***\r\n
End\r\n***To Here***
End\r\n
Other things
```

The regex can't match the second `\r\nEnd\r\n` because the prefixed `\r\n` has already been captured.

Try:

```
temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"(?<=\r\n)End(?=\r\n)+", "}");
```

Using the non-capturing grouping `(?<=)` and `(?=)` you can solve the problem (but note that being non-capturing, you can't replace what is matched in the `(?<=)` and `(?=)`, so the difference in the replaced text `"}"`)